# Fixed Width Editor/Plugin

Tags: text-editor, fixed-width

Some of my recent projects have relied on creating flat files that have fixed-width fields. I tried finding an editor that would allow me to mark field using the widths and inspect the data visually, but I have been unsuccessful.

I found RecordEditor through google, but I found it to be clunky.

I tried using style tokens within notepad++, but it is limited to 5, and if a field is completely whitespace, it highlights all the whitespace in the file.

Comment: This is similar to question to http://superuser.com/questions/55912/syntax-highlight-a-flatfile/

Comment: That question doesn't answer my question, as the only answers given are 1. Program your own solution and 2. Use recordEditor,(which I noted).

Comment: It does show how to setup highlighting using Regex (VIM). VIM, EMacs, JEdit all support regex highlighting. It also indicates there aren't many solutions out there

Comment: Also the link is for other people so they give the VIM type answers

Comment: I don't consider using regex highlighting a good solution to my question. I agree, it just seems like there isn't something out there.